# Login Auth with Python, Phpmyadmin, problem in "SELECT"

Tags: python, select, authentication, phpmyadmin

```
I've a problem in this SELECT:
```

Premise:

I made a script that create a Database with a 'Key' that is a password encrypted -> code of encrypt:

```
import base64
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import  default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

password_provided = "password"  # input
password = password_provided.encode()   # Convert in type byte

salt = b'\xaes\xff\x80\xe2| (\xfcG\xbdk\xedxb9\x15n7'
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
    algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
    length=32,
    salt=salt,
    iterations=100000,
    backend=default_backend()
)
key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password)) #can only use kdf once
print(key)
```

Now I'm trying to do an AUTH with method POST, I start trying with some SELECT for 'search' the password for the log and find a method to compare the string not encrypted with the encrypted string for login I try:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE password = %s", (key) #Problem!

mycursor.execute(sql)

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  print(x)
```

My output is :

```
**  File "login.py", line 12, in <module>
    mycursor.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/jhon/prova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 536, in execute
    stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
**
```

I try to do "key1 = key.encode()" , but it's wrong... 
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

This line creates a 2-tuple of a string and an int and assigns it to variable "sql":

> sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE password = %s", (key) #Problem!

"(key)" does not produce a 1-tuple; to do that you want "(key,)".  It looks like you wanted to create a 2-tuple of a string followed by a 1-tuple.

Then this line sends the 2-tuple you created as a single argument to the method being called:

> mycursor.execute(sql)

If this is the library you are using, then the docstring for the function definition execute (see line 183) here...: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/master/lib/mysql/connector/cursor.py

... shows that you want to specify your query pattern fill-in values using an n-tuple as the second function argument to .execute(...).  You can do that with the variadic argument operator a.k.a. sequence-unpack operator (mentioned as part of https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558), or you can separate them out.  So you might want code like this:

> sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE password = %s"
>
> values = (key,)
>
> mycursor.execute(sql, values)

or

> sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE password = %s", (key,)
>
> # star operator inside function call unpacks sequence variable by one level into separate arguments.
>
> mycursor.execute(*sql)